# How professional ASP.NET Web Form developers code database view pages?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Just wondering what method professionals choose for a page for viewing data from a database table in ASP.NET Web Forms, for example a single product details page on an ecommerce website?

Some of the methods I consider are:

1. Data bound DetailsView;
2. Data bound FormView;
3. Lots of label controls assigned values in the code-behind;
4. Lots of Response.Writes on the markup page (eg. <%= object.field %>); or,
5. Any other methods???
6. The code excerpt below is the method I am using at present. Is it bad practice?

Markup...

```
<asp:Panel ID="panOrder" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Order Number</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblOrderId" runat="server" Text='<%# Order.orderid %>' /></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Order Date</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCreationDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Order.creationdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>' /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Code behind...

```
protected order Order { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int orderId = Request.QueryString["orderid"] == null ? 0 : Utilities.IntParse(Request.QueryString["orderid"]);
    Order = order.SelectByOrderId(orderId);
    panOrder.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you need in specific situation:

1. use `DetailsView` if you need simple operations on your data (basic select, update, insert) and your data will be presented in single view in a list (top to bottom)
2. the same as for DetailsView but keep in mind that with `FormView` you are more free of how to present your data out of the box (DetailsView need some tweaks to behave the same). You won't be limited to top to bottom presentation, you can freely choose where on your page some info is presented.
3. when you have only 2 to 3 databound elements maybe, but when you have more fields I would rather go for one of the above methods. It is easier.
4. this method in webforms I personally use very rarely. Maybe if you have to redesign some old ASP (any non webforms) page where is a lot of HTML to handle, and is already structured nicely?
5. using other Data controls too, like Gridview when presenting tabular data for example. Repeater is also another nice control like Muhammad mentioned (I agree it is the most customizable).

Sorry for so long answer. I was wondering the same question couple of years back too, so I thought it is in place to share this with you. The above helped me a lot when identifying methods to show this or that in webforms.

To answer your given example: Single products details page will be easiest to achieve with DetailsView or FormView. I would go for the second one.

Comment: I use classes as business objects representing my tables, and List<object> for multiple rows. I can't databind my single records to detailsview, formview or repeater. Is this bad practice to have these types of BO's or should I always use a List?

Comment: I think I don't quite understand your question... can't bind single records of a List<>? You can search for it (like here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx)). If this is not it just ask a new question here on SO with all the details and example code of your further problem with List<> and databinding to DetailsView etc.;)

Comment: My single records are not List<object>, just object. I have edited my question above with code examples of how I am doing things at present, just wanted an opinion on whether there was any issues with doing it this way.

Comment: @John: I personally try to avoid this type of coding. What you should do is write some middle layer between your current classes as business objects representing your tables (POCOs) and controls that will display your data (html). By middle layer I mean static methods that already return `DataSet` or `DataTable` objects which you could then easily bind to web data controls using `ObjectDataSource`. 2 very helpful resources: [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/IntroductionTo3TierArchitecture.aspx) and [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/3-Tier-Architecture-Examples.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the product details on the page, you should use the [Repeater Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx) instead. This way you will have more control of the layout of the page. In addition this control is `light weight` and will provide you with good `performance`.

Comment: What I meant was a single product details page, not a list of products.

Comment: Despite its name, there are no problems in using a repeater to display a single record.

Comment: I know you are talking to show single record, of product Details.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. I hadn't considered using a repeater for a single record.